# All the controls in visual studio windows form invisible while loading it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In Visual Studio 2010 , while loading a visual c# form, the form comes up, but all the controls in it, and everything has become invisible.

I'm getting the following error:

> Warning   1    'EIM.Form2.Name' hides inherited member 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Name'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.   C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio
>    2010\Projects\EIM\EIM\Form2.Designer.cs    1172    44  EIM

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How does your form look like? Show code!

Comment: Did you declare a `Name` property in your form class?

Comment: An excellent question: no code, no answers to the questions

Answer (score 0):

It's because the **base members** are not being called. When you declare a `Name` property in your derivative class, you hide the `Name` member for your base class. Therefore, when your form is compiled, your derivative will be called rather than the base, and your controls become "invisible".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what aevitas said I guess the problem only occurs while the form is *loading*? One reason could be that you're performing some long-lasting action in the `Load` event of the form. This causes the form to be shown, but everything is either invisible or unusable.

Try putting the code that performs this long-lasting operation into the `Shown` event, which is called *after* the form was shown and all controls were initialized.